# Popover closing on selection of ComboBox

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm facing a weird issue with my Responsive Popover. It is autoclosing itself when I select an item from my ComboxBox.

I don't want a modal where other UI is blocked. Clicking anywhere should close the popover. I'm unable to find the root cause of the issue.

Below are the coding details:

**Instantiating Popover:**

```
                openFilter : function( oEvent ){
                    if (!this.actionPopUpFragment) {
                        this.getView().addDependent(this.actionPopUpFragment, this);
                        //this._oPopover.bindElement("/ProductCollection/0");

                    }
                    var oButton = oEvent.getSource();
                    // jQuery.sap.delayedCall(0, this, function () {
                        this.actionPopUpFragment.openBy(oButton);
                        if (this.actionPopUpFragment._oControl && this.actionPopUpFragment._oControl.oPopup) {
                            // this.actionPopUpFragment._oControl.oPopup.setAutoClose(false);
                        }
                    // });
            },
```

**Fragment.xml :**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<ResponsivePopover
    class=" formPopup"
    placement="Bottom"
    contentWidth='30rem'
    showCloseButton='true'
    contentHeight='27rem'
    showHeader='false'
    afterOpen='onAfterOpen'>
    <content>
        <mvc:XMLView class="formBox" viewName="sap.hana.cst.common.graph/ui/form"/> 

    </content>
</ResponsivePopover>
```

**View Embedded inside fragment:**

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="sap.hana.cst.common.graph.controller.Form" 
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
xmlns="sap.m" 
xmlns:table="sap.ui.table" 
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" 
xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" 
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                      
xmlns:control = "sap.hana.cst.common.graph.control">
<Page showHeader='true' class='pageClass'>
    <ComboBox class='OperatorClass' selectedKey="{operator}" items="{
                    path: 'optionsModel>/operators',
                    sorter: { path: 'operatorModel>text' }
                  }">
        <core:Item key="{optionsModel>key}" text="{optionsModel>text}" />

    </ComboBox>
</Page>
```

**Data for testing :**

```
var aOperators = [
            {
                    key:"EqualsTo",
                    text:"="
            },
            {
                    key:"NotEqualsTo",
                    text:"!="
            },
            {
                    key:"GreaterThan",
                    text:">"
            },
            {
                    key:"LessThan",
                    text:"<"
            },
            {
                    key:"GreaterThanOrEqualsTo",
                    text:">="
            },
            {
                    key:"LessThanOrEqualsTo",
                    text:"<="
            }
        ];


        var oOptionsModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({operators: aOperators});
        this.getView().setModel(oOptionsModel, "optionsModel");
```

**Error GIF :**
[image]

Comment: that is a bug with the internal focus management in sapui5. If you force the focus on a popover element in the selection event of your combo box it should be ok :)

Comment: Since the behavior is not reproducible with any of the current supported versions, I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

I found an elegant solution. The source code of PopOver gives a valuable hint pointing out the problem.

```
PopOver.js -> onFocusEvent()
// focus/blur for handling autoclose is disabled for desktop browsers which are not in the touch simulation mode
// create timeout for closing the popup if there is no focus immediately returning to the popup
```

Means, you need to refocus the PopOver after user interaction or loading data immediately. The auto closing feature of PopOver is using a timer. In my case I had a backend call delaying a few seconds.. Since I refocus the PopOver *before* i do the backend call, everything works fine.

I think in your example there is the same problem. Maybe you load you combo with backend data. Just add `this.byId("myPopOver").focus()` before your backend call and your combo should not auto close.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you to solve your problem

```
$('#popoverId').popover({
    html: true,
    title: 'Popover Title<a class="close" href="#");">&times;</a>',
    content: $('#popoverContent').html(),
});

$('#popoverId').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (($('.popover').has(e.target).length == 0) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
        $('#popoverId').popover('hide');
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Niketan: I did:  `$('#' + this.actionPopUpFragment._oControl.getId()).click(function (e) {
          // debugger;
          e.stopPropagation();
         });` where _oControl is my Popover. However, after this my ComboBox are not showing options.